# Updating context after db modification using a stored procedure

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

In a Silverlight application I use a stored procedure to update a table of my data base.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[SP_ADD_MIS_MISSION] 
(
    @IdMission as int,
    @IdVersion as smallint,
    @LibMission as varchar (50)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @IDNEWVERSION as int = 1,
        @IDNEWMISSION as int = @IdMission,
        @supp as bit = 1
BEGIN
        IF @IdMission != 0 AND @IdMission is not NULL
        BEGIN
            SELECT @IDNEWVERSION = MAX(IDVERSION)+1 FROM MIS_Mission where MIS_Mission.IdMission=@IdMission

            Update MIS_Mission SET Suppression = @supp WHERE MIS_Mission.IdMission=@IdMission AND MIS_Mission.IdVersion=(@IDNEWVERSION-1)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @IDNEWVERSION = 1
            select @IDNEWMISSION = MAX(MIS_Mission.IdMission)+1 from MIS_Mission

            if @IDNEWMISSION is NULL SET @IDNEWMISSION=1
        END

        Insert MIS_Mission ( IdMission,
                             IdVersion,
                             LibMission,
                             Suppression
                           )

                    values ( @IDNEWMISSION,
                             @IDNEWVERSION,
                             @LibMission,
                             @Suppression
                           )
        SELECT @IDNEWMISSION
END
```

I added this code in my WCF RIA services to launch the stored procedure:

```
public void SetMission(MIS_Mission mis)
{
    _entity.ADD_MIS_MISSION(mis.IdMission,mis.IdVersion,mis.LibMission);
}
```

And I added this code in my Silverlight application to update my database whith the value enter in my datagrid :

```
private void UpdateMission_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    foreach(MIS_Mission mis in dG_Mission.ItemsSource)
    {
        var operation = _Context.SetMission(mis);

        operation.Completed += (se, ev) =>
        {
        };
    }
}
```

But when I finished to update my database, my context didn't updat whith the new values of IdVersion, and my datagrid display the old versions of my missions.

How can I update my context without reload my datagrid?

Comment: does `_Context.SetMission(mis);` trigger event? If yes you need to assign  `operation.Completed += (se, ev) =>` before you call it. If no, you need to fire event which will trigger `operation.Completed` after you attach it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. my `operation.Completed +=` seems working this way. When I try I have no problem.

Comment: do you retrieve data from database once you updated it? if not, your application may not know you have updated anything.  If you don't want to re-query database, you need to store underlying data in `List<>` or any other structure and rebind `datagrid` to it after each update to DB. Another approach is to use `DataBinding` with implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` - with this approach your UI `datagrid` will be automatically updated from underlying structure.

Comment: I think it isn't possible to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` because my primary key change at each update (idmission+idversion)

Comment: In this case, sadly, your only option is to re-query data from database after each update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution on this website : http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2009/11/24/refresh-the-cached-entityset-after-a-submitchanges-wcf-ria-services.aspx

My solution is like this:

```
private void UpdateMission_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int countenr = itemsSource.Count;

    foreach(MIS_Mission mis in dG_Mission.ItemsSource)
    {
        var operation = _Context.SetMission(mis);

        operation.Completed += (se, ev) =>
        {
            countenr--;
            if (countenr == 0)
            {
                _Context.Load<MIS_Mission>(
                    _Context.ListMissionQuery(),
                    LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent,
                    loadOperation =>
                    {
                       if (loadOperation.HasError)
                       {
                           MessageBox.Show(loadOperation.Error.Message);
                           loadOperation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           List<MIS_Mission> itemsource = dG_Mission.ItemsSource as List<MIS_Mission>;
                           var results = itemsource.Where(entity => !loadOperation.Entities.Contains(entity)).ToList();

                           results.ForEach(entity => itemsource.Remove(entity));

                           results = loadOperation.Entities.Where(entity => !itemsource.Contains(entity)).ToList();

                           results.ForEach(entity => itemsource.Add(entity));

                       }
                   }
                   ,null
               );
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This solution work fine for me but the refresh of the datagrid is a bit slow.

Thanks for your help
bye